# Optional whitespaces inside lookbehind regex

Tags: regex

Using Smarty template engine, but looking to pre-process HTML to change font-size across all CSS.

I want to make the whitespace(s) optional after the colon so it will match the number no matter what.

The issue is I can only seem to get optional matching as part of the expression, not the lookbehind.

RegEx: `(?<=font-size: )[0-9]+`

HTML excerpt:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt; 
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display:block;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use lookbehinds when you can do it easily with a capturing group.

In your case you can do something like:

```
(\bfont-size:\s*)([0-9]+)
```

Then use the capturing groups `$1` and `$2` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Reg ex symbol for white space `\s` so is this what you need: `(?<=font-size:\s?)[0-9]+`?